# Importing express router from es6 module

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my first nodeJS project and im getting stuck already. In the package.json "type" = "module".
I keep getting an error "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND".
I tried default and named export but both didnt work.

productRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ msg: 'get products' });
});

export default router;
```

server.js

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import routes from './api/v1/routes/productRoutes';

// express app
const app = express();

// middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.path, req.method);
  next();
});

// routes
app.use('/api/products', routes);

// connect to db
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to database');
    // listen to port
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log('listening for requests on port', process.env.PORT);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: `"productRoutes" !== "productRouter"`

Comment: @jonrsharpe typo in my question. My file is called productRoutes.js,

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide extension of a js file `.js` the node compiler doesn't understand it, unless you use some other transpilers like babel.

so change
`import routes from './api/v1/routes/productRoutes';`
to
`import routes from './api/v1/routes/productRoutes.js';`