# How can I import a route file using Express?

Tags: javascript, express, graphql

Normally when I make a server I have no problem importing route files but I'm working on a project using GraphQL which requires me to include `"type": "module",` inside my `package.json` file. So when I try having this inside my `app.js` file

`const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");`

It gives me this error.

`ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead`

How do I use import for a file like that? Inside that file is a bunch of `router.get` functions like this:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("index", { title: "Library" });
});

router.get("/library/:title", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("library");
});
```

Would I have to manually export every render? Or is there a simpler solution I can't seem to figure out?

Comment: You may refer the following URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74657169/importing-express-router-from-es6-module

Comment: @TheKNVB That's not actually the same error, and for different reasons. Simply replace the `require` with `await import`, as the `require` function is non-standard javascript that isn't supported when you run your files as standard  JS modules. The issue is, however, that you might not import anything from your route if you use `modules.export`, as that's also a non-standard export system.

Comment: @somethinghere so `await import routes from "./routes/index.js";` ?

Comment: I think in this case you are probably going to have to do `await import("./routes/index.js")` and see what is returned (I am unsure how node handles old style modules) and take it from there (it could just be `.default`, it could also just be the entire `module.` object that is imported, I'm unsure at this point). If you use the full import syntax (like `import x from ""`, `await` is unnecessary and will probably cause issues, as imports declared at the top of your file will be awaited automatically as they are required)

Answer (score 2):

You should create a file "../routes/index.js" which looks like:

```
import Express from 'express';
const router = Express.Router();

router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("index", { title: "Library" });
});

router.get("/library/:title", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("library");
});

export default router;
```

And then convert the following statement:

```
const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
```

into

```
 import indexRouter from "../routes/index.js";
```